# Pandas df.index.strftime('%H')

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am working with time series data, but for SO purposes Ill just make up some time series data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint


rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=500, freq='6H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 10, 500)}, index=rng)
```

Im trying to create some dummy variables which will ultimately be used for a stats regression model. Float to represent hour of the day...

```
df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H')
```

The question that I have, is why doesn't the `df['hour']` populate in the summary statistics of the `df.describe`? different data type??

```
df.describe()
```

Returns:

```
Random_Number
count   500.00
mean    5.1140
std     2.6219
min     1.000
25%     3.000
50%     5.000
75%     7.000
max     9.000
```

Ultimetely this is where I am stuck, I am trying to create a dummy variable that will either be a `1` or `0` depending on if the `hour` is between 6AM and 6PM. The code runs without any error:

```
df['daytime'] = np.where(df['hour'].isin([6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]), 1, 0)
```

But with another `df.describe()` its like the `hour` df is not getting created properly. Is there another/better way of accomplishing this???

```
    Random_Number   daytime
count   500.000000  500.0
mean    5.128000    0.0
std     2.587858    0.0
min     1.000000    0.0
25%     3.000000    0.0
50%     5.000000    0.0
75%     7.000000    0.0
max     9.000000    0.0
```

Comment: because `strftime` gives you string type, while `describe` only works with number type?

Comment: Use `df.index.hour`. The `strftime` methods are only really useful when you need to output to some very specific format.  When you use it you're back to  the `Object` dtype which basically defeats the entire purpose of converting to `datetime64` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string Hour to int and then apply the function:

```
df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')

df['daytime'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda hr : 1 if (hr > 6 and hr < 18) else 0)


df.describe()
```

Results in

```
Random_Number   hour    daytime
count 500.000000 500.000000 500.000000
mean 4.914000   9.000000    0.250000
std 2.539982    6.714922    0.433446
min 1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25% 3.000000    4.500000    0.000000
50% 5.000000    9.000000    0.000000
75% 7.000000    13.500000   0.250000
max 9.000000    18.000000   1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

`describe()` is not working because hour has type object, you should cast it to integer

```
df.hour = df.hour.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time) then flag the rows with `.isin`

```
ilocs = df.index.indexer_between_time('6:00', '18:00')
df['daytime'] = pd.Series(range(len(df)), index=df.index).isin(ilocs).astype(int)
```